# jQuery Basic Slider - change next/prev text control with button control

Tags: html

I am using Basic jQuery Slider( http://www.basic-slider.com). I am getting the slider on my page and it is working perfectly. But now I want button controls using next/prev image (<,>). I tried to disable the next/prev text but it is showing "undefined" in controls part. How can I change the controls with Image?? 
I am providing code of html and css. For JS file, I am uploding it and sharing the link. Anyone know the solution please help. Thanx in advance.

js link
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ab23bbe3r1lixh/bjqs-1.3.min.js?dl=0

html code for slider

```
<div class="slider">
    <ul class="bjqs">
       <li><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/banner01.jpg" width="100%" height="386px"></li>
       <li><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/banner02.jpg" width="100%" height="386px"></li>
       <li><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/banner03.jpg" width="100%" height="386px"></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

css file

```
/* Basic jQuery Slider styles */

.slider img { display:block; }
.slider { margin:0 auto; width: 100%; box-shadow: 0px 50px 0px #0F0;}

ul.bjqs
{
position:relative;
list-style-type:none; 
padding:0;
margin:0;
overflow:hidden;
display:none;
}

li.bjqs-slide
{
position:absolute; 
display:none;
}

ul.bjqs-controls
{
list-style:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
z-index:9999;
}

ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li a{position:absolute;}
ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li.bjqs-next a{right:0;}
ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li.bjqs-prev a{left:0;}
ol.bjqs-markers{list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; width:100%;}
ol.bjqs-markers.h-centered{text-align: center;}
ol.bjqs-markers li{display:inline;}
ol.bjqs-markers li a{display:inline-block;}
p.bjqs-caption{display:block;width:96%;margin:0;padding:2%;position:absolute;bottom:0;}

.bjqs-markers{ display:none; }

ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li a{
display:block;
padding:10px;
background:#fff;
color:#000;
text-decoration: none;
}

ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li a:hover{
background:#000;
color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> http://www.basic-slider.com link is not working. I created a slider. Please check.

[Slider Plunker][1]

```
  [1]: https://plnkr.co/edit/iTq8urcfpB9cBp2onuWT?p=preview
```